# bash awk get numbers in two digits

Tags: bash, awk

I want to correct wrong meta data or add missing meta data for the 75 cd's I have ripped from disc.
I got the track info from AllMusic en stripped it to almost usable "CSV" data.

```
Number";"1";"Piece";"Nocturne for piano No. 2 in E flat major, Op. 9/2, CT. 109";"Componist";"Frédéric Chopin
MainPiece";"";"Piece";"Symphony No. 9 in E minor ("From the New World"), B. 178 (Op. 95) (first published as No. 5)
Number";"2";"Piece";"Largo";"Componist";"Antonin Dvorák
Number";"3";"Piece";"La plus que lente, waltz for piano (or orchestra), L. 121";"Componist";"Claude Debussy
Number";"4";"Piece";"Waldesrauschen (Forest Murmurs), for piano (Zwei Konzertetuden No. 1), S. 145/1 (LW A218/1)";"Componist";"Franz Liszt
MainPiece";"";"Piece";"Oboe Concerto, for oboe, strings & continuo in D minor, Op. 8/9, RV 454
Number";"5";"Piece";"Allegro";"Componist";"Antonio Vivaldi
Number";"6";"Piece";"Largo";"Componist";"Antonio Vivaldi
Number";"7";"Piece";"Allegro";"Componist";"Antonio Vivaldi
MainPiece";"";"Piece";"Cello Concerto in A major, G. 475
Number";"8";"Piece";"1. Allegro";"Componist";"Luigi Boccherini
Number";"9";"Piece";"2. Adagio";"Componist";"Luigi Boccherini
Number";"10";"Piece";"3. Rondò - Allegro";"Componist";"Luigi Boccherini
MainPiece";"";"Piece";"Serenade No. 12 for winds in C minor ("Nacht Musique"), K. 388 (K. 384a)
Number";"11";"Piece";"Allegro";"Componist";"Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart
Number";"12";"Piece";"Liebesträume, notturno for piano No. 3 in A flat major ("O Lieb, so lang du lieben kannst"), S. 541/3 (LW A103/3)";"Componist";"Franz Liszt
MainPiece";"";"Piece";"Phantasiestücke (4) for violin, cello & piano in A minor, Op. 88
Number";"13";"Piece";"Romanze";"Componist";"Robert Schumann
MainPiece";"";"Piece";"Sinfonia Concertante for violin, cello, oboe, bassoon & orchestra, H. 1/105
Number";"14";"Piece";"Andante";"Componist";"Franz Joseph Haydn
```

I would like to rewrite this with awk to a script to set meta data
`eyeD3 -n 01 -a composer -t mainpiece piece 01*.mp3`

And with awk to rename the files
`mv 01*.mp3 01 [composer] mainpiece piece.mp3`

The mainpiece / piece is an manual part but I would like to rewrite 1 to 01.

I found something with `printf ("%2d" ,$1,$2)` but thins complaints about `.mp3`

Has anyone suggestions for me?

Comment: It looks like your almost there. As we always encourage new posters: please show us the code you are using, and show us actual output and any error messages. It makes it much easier to provide help and avoids "20 questions" in the comments.  Rather than have `awk` perform the `mv` command, I'd recommend that you have `awk` "emit" text that can be passed to the shell to execute.But it will help if you include an example `mv` command you need, say for line 1 of your CSV file. Good luck.

Comment: `printf("%2d", $1. $2)` only prints `$1`, and if it is 0..9, then there is a blank before the digit.  If you want to print `$1` and `$2`, you need `printf("%d%d", $1, $2)`; if you want to print `$1` with two digits and a leading zero if necessary, then either `printf("%.2d", $1)` or `printf("%02d", $1)` will do the job.  If you are renaming files from/to names with spaces, you'll need to use double quotes around the file names (or single quotes).

Comment: The data you show is in an intriguing format.  It appears to be using `";"` as the separator in what is otherwise a 'comma-separated values' format file. It clearly isn't truly 'comma-separated' format, but the name CSV is often used for similar formats such as this.

Comment: Dear Jonathan, I at first had the idea to make manual changes within Excel and Excel works with ";" you are right CSV uses only , I believe.

Comment: Dear Shellter, I have a script that at first stripes a lot of unnecessary codes from original html, with this result I generate a script to edit meta data and rename file names.

awk -F '";"' '{print "eyeD3 -n " $2 " -a #.#" $6 "#.# -t #.#"$4"#.# " $2"*.mp3"}' "CT1000-Disc-$(printf %02d $d)f.html" > "CT1000-Disc-$(printf %02d $d)g.html"

awk -F '";"' '{print "mv " $2 "*.mp3 #.#"$2" ["$6"] "$4"#.#.mp3"}' "CT1000-Disc-$(printf %02d $d)f.html" > "CT1000-Disc-$(printf %02d $d)i.html"

Comment: the results I automatically rewrite to a usable script where I only have to change 1 to 01 twice per line and the MainPiece for example "Symphony" I have to cut and paste before "part 1", "part 2", "part 3"
01 Symphony Part 1
02 Symphony Part 2
03 Symphony Part 3

Comment: @JeroenRuijter :  that's interesting looking code, but the place to put it is in your question above. I can't read or be sure the syntax is correct reading it like that. If you're going to mention a user's name in a comment use @ userNameAllOneWord so they'll get a notification of the message. AND sample data to solve one "set" would be easier to understand for the other readers here. Good luck.